# Several errors in LaTeX algorithm environment

Tags: algorithmicx, pseudocode, algorithmic

Hello guys i am new to LaTeX, i have written an algorithm in algorithm environment which is as follows:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Reduct Construction Algorithm}\label{euclid}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Procedure{Reduct Construction}{}\newline
        \textbf{Input:} Three matrices based on indiscernibility, discernibility and equal to one relations.\newline
        \textbf{Output:} Reducts (sentences)

\State {{\text{\,\,\,\,\,} \textbf{for} i = 2 to n \text{\,\,\,\,\,}}

\State {{\text{\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,} \textbf{for} j = 1 to n-1 \text{\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,}}

\State {\text{\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,} \textbf{if}$M(i,j) \neq \phi$ \text{\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,}\textbf{then}

\State {{\text{\,\,\,\,\,} \textbf{for} every non-empty element M(i`,j`) \in B \text{\,\,\,\,\,}}

\State {{\text{\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,} \textbf{if} $M(i`,j`)\subset M(i,j)$   \text{\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,}\textbf{then}}

\State {{\text{\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,} $M(i,j) = M(i`,j`)$ \text{\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,}}

\State {{\text{\,\,\,\,\,} Divide M(i,j) into two parts\text{\,\,\,\,\,}}

\State {{\text{\,\,\,\,\,} \textbf{Select} an attribute a from M(i,j); \text{\,\,\,\,\,}}

\State {{\text{\,\,\,\,\,} $A = M(i,j)-\{a\}$ \text{\,\,\,\,\,}}

\State {{\text{\,\,\,\,\,} $M(i,j)=\{a\}$ \text{\,\,\,\,\,}}

\State {{\text{\,\,\,\,\,} Simplify every non empty element in B \text{\,\,\,\,\,}}

\State {{\text{\,\,\,\,\,} \textbf{if} {$a \in M(i`,j`)$} \text{\,\,\,\,\,}\textbf{then}

\State {{\text{\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,} $M(i`,j`)=\{a\}$ \text{\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,}}

\State {{\text{\,\,\,\,\,} \textbf{Else} \text{\,\,\,\,\,}}
\State {{\text{\,\,\,\,\,} $M(i`,j`) =  M(i`,j`)- A$ \text{\,\,\,\,\,}}

\end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

the packages i am using are:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
```

there are alot of errors, although the visuallization is correct but when i run first time no pdf is generated on run time which is pathetic, the errors are

```
Package algorithmicx Error: Some blocks are not closed!!!. \end{algorithmic}
Missing } inserted. \end{algorithmic}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \Procedure
Missing $ inserted. ...{for} every non-empty element M(i`,j`) \in
Extra }, or forgotten $. ... element M(i`,j`) \in B \text{\,\,\,\,\,}}
```

i've tried to correct them but failed, any help correcting these errors would be helpful, thanks

Comment: Please, edit your code and post the complete code so we can compile it.

Comment: @Sigur edited i hope it helps now.

Comment: Your code appears to have a lot of inconsistent material. See the documentation http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misusing the tool:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Reduct Construction Algorithm}\label{euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Reduct Construction}{}\newline
\textbf{Input:} Three matrices based on indiscernibility, discernibility and equal to one relations.\newline
\textbf{Output:} Reducts (sentences)
\For{$i = 2$ to $n$}
  \For{$j = 1$ to $n-1$}
    \If{$M(i,j) \neq \emptyset$}
      \For{every non-empty element $M(i',j') \in B$}
        \If{$M(i',j')\subset M(i,j)$}
           \State{$M(i,j) = M(i',j')$}
        \EndIf
      \EndFor
    \EndIf
    \State{Divide $M(i,j)$ into two parts}
    \State{\textbf{Select} an attribute $a$ from $M(i,j)$;}
    \State{$A = M(i,j)-\{a\}$}
    \State{$M(i,j)=\{a\}$}
    \State{Simplify every non empty element in $B$}
    \If{$a \in M(i',j')$}
      \State{$M(i',j')=\{a\}$}
    \Else
      \State {$M(i',j') =  M(i',j')- A$}
    \EndIf
  \EndFor
\EndFor
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not sure the realization is exactly what you have in mind, but it should be easy to adjust it.

Note that math symbols should always be between `$` signs. For priming a symbol, use an apostrophe `'`, not a backquote `` ` ``

Comment: It was really helpful for me to use the tool correctly, thanks a lot for your help mate.